# Git push to GitHub via SSH keeps re-prompting for SSH password with correct password

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-lfs

I am trying to push my code to a brand new repo that I created in GitHub.

First I created the repo on GitHub by running gh in WSL 2 for a repository running in Windows user space (under /mnt/c/Users/...).

```
gh repo create aob --private --remote origin -s .
✓ Created repository RobRoseKnows/aob on GitHub
✓ Added remote git@github.com:RobRoseKnows/aob.git
```

This worked as expected, and the GitHub repo is empty. Then I tried to push the repo with `git push origin main`, but it kept re-prompting me when I entered my passphrase for my ssh key. I thought perhaps my passphrase was wrong, but I used both `ssh-keygen -y` and `ssh -T git@github.com` to confirm that yes my passphrase is correct.

So I tried running with GIT_TRACE=1 on:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin main
21:45:12.488728 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git push origin main
21:45:12.510288 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; ssh git@github.com 'git-receive-pack '\''RobRoseKnows/aob.git'\'''
Enter passphrase for key '/home/robr/.ssh/id_rsa':
21:45:16.047842 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: .git/hooks/pre-push origin git@github.com:RobRoseKnows/aob.git
21:45:16.057035 git.c:742               trace: exec: git-lfs pre-push origin git@github.com:RobRoseKnows/aob.git
21:45:16.057076 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git-lfs pre-push origin git@github.com:RobRoseKnows/aob.git
21:45:16.059471 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'version'
21:45:16.060407 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'remote' '-v'
21:45:16.072261 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'remote'
21:45:16.088917 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' 'HEAD' '--symbolic-full-name' 'HEAD'
21:45:16.121434 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' '--git-dir' '--show-toplevel'
21:45:16.133627 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '--includes' '-l'
21:45:16.142217 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
21:45:16.148398 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '--includes' '-l' '--blob' ':.lfsconfig'
21:45:16.158110 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '--includes' '-l' '--blob' 'HEAD:.lfsconfig'
21:45:16.185855 trace git-lfs: attempting pure SSH protocol connection
21:45:16.185875 trace git-lfs: spawning pure SSH connection
21:45:16.185909 trace git-lfs: run_command: ssh -oControlMaster=auto -oControlPath=/mnt/wslg/runtime-dir/git-lfs/sock-%C git@github.com git-lfs-transfer RobRoseKnows/aob.git upload
21:45:16.185997 trace git-lfs: exec: ssh '-oControlMaster=auto' '-oControlPath=/mnt/wslg/runtime-dir/git-lfs/sock-%C' 'git@github.com' 'git-lfs-transfer RobRoseKnows/aob.git upload'
Enter passphrase for key '/home/robr/.ssh/id_rsa':

21:45:19.504729 trace git-lfs: pure SSH connection successful
21:45:19.504752 trace git-lfs: pure SSH protocol connection failed: Unable to negotiate version with remote side (unable to read capabilities): EOF
21:45:19.504961 trace git-lfs: pre-push: refs/heads/main 780d657533fe4dc580c62b5865ebfb5f17f51d34 refs/heads/main 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
21:45:19.506392 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: creating pattern ".git" of type gitignore
21:45:19.506412 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: creating pattern "**/.git" of type gitignore
21:45:19.507325 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "tmp"

Exiting because of "interrupt" signal.
```

Is this some issue with git-lfs? I found [this](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1044) but I'm not sure if that's my issue or how to fix it.

`git lfs -v` shows 3.4.0, which is close to the latest version.

Here's the output of `git config -l`:

```
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
alias.amend=commit --amend --no-edit
alias.authors=shortlog --summary --email --numbered
alias.b=branch -v -v
alias.co=checkout
alias.l=log --pretty=oneline -n 20 --graph --abbrev-commit
alias.ll=!git l | fzf-tmux --ansi --multi --preview 'git show --color=always {+2}'
alias.st=status --short --branch
alias.start=!git init && git commit -n --allow-empty -m "initial empty commit"
alias.svn-diff=!git-svn-diff
alias.up=pull --rebase --autostash
alias.who=log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset - %C(blue)a: %an <%ae>%Creset %C(green)c: %cn <%ce>%Creset - %s'
alias.pr=!git fetch -fu ${2:-origin} refs/pull/$1/head:pr/$1 && :
alias.pr-clean=!git for-each-ref refs/heads/pr/* --format='%(refname)' | while read ref ; do branch=${ref#refs/heads/} ; git branch -D $branch ; done
color.ui=auto
color.diff.meta=normal
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore_global
core.attributesfile=~/.gitignore_global
core.whitespace=space-before-tab,-indent-with-non-tab,trailing-space
diff.vim.command=vimdiff
log.decorate=short
log.follow=true
pull.rebase=true
push.default=simple
rerere.enabled=1
user.email={{REDACTED}}
user.name=Rob Rose
include.path=~/.gitconfig_local
user.email={{REDACTED}}
user.name=Rob Rose
user.signingkey={{REDACTED}}
commit.gpgsign=true
url.git@github.com:.pushinsteadof=https://github.com/
url.git@github.com:.pushinsteadof=git://github.com/
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
init.defaulbranch=main
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
lfs.repositoryformatversion=0
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:RobRoseKnows/aob.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `git push` with Git LFS, first Git gets the list of remote references, which happens over SSH (requiring your password), and then it calls the pre-push hook to invoke Git LFS.  Git LFS also must make an SSH connection, first to try the pure SSH connection, and then to fall back to the hybrid connection.  Git LFS cannot use the same connection as Git, so it must make some of its own.

If you don't want to be prompted for your password multiple times, then you should use an SSH agent.  You can do that in a terminal with `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`.  Once you've done that, you can use `ssh-add` to add your keys, and then you shouldn't be prompted until the shell session expires.